# C# Interop.Excel Нужна помощь в описании синтаксиса при работе с .xlsx файлами

Tags: c#, excel

Имеется

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace SqlToXlsx_v._1._0
{
    class Program
    {
        //Массив ссылок на созданные книги и на конкретную книгу
        private Excel.Workbooks xlsAppWorkbooks;
        private Excel.Workbook xlsAppWorkbook;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fName = (DateTime.Now.ToString("DD_MM_HH")+ "_Тестовое имя");
            var fType = ".xlsx";
            Excel.Application xlsApp;
            //Создание экземпляра Эксель
            xlsApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlsApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1;           
            xlsApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

            ////////////////////////////////
            ///Здесь sql рожает dataTable///
            ////////////////////////////////
            ///И dataTable заполняет таблицу
            ////////////////////////////////

            //Сохраняем книгу после редактирования
            xlsAppWorkbook.SaveAs(@"C:\stat\{1}{2}", fName, fType);

            //закрытие экземпляра
            xlsApp.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Находит ошибку в "SaveAs".

> Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Program.xlsAppWorkbook"
>   требуется ссылка на объект.

Comment: Какую ошибку? Добавьте ее в вопрос.

Comment: Если вы переделали и у вас теперь новые затруднения - лучше задать новый вопрос. На этот уже ответ дан и ваша правка делает этот ответ бессмысленным. )

Comment: Настоятельно рекомендую НЕ использовать интероп для работы с екселем.
Альтернативные варианты и детали почему так можно найти сдесь:
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb там же и простая либа для взаимодействия с ексель файлами.

Comment: Я бы не советовал иметь дело с Интеропом вовсе.
Детально про причины почему так, я расписывал вооот сдесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560133/c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-excel-%d0%a1sv-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b Там же сможешь подобрать себе другой путь по взаимодействию с екселем или же взять указаный там код если тебе будет достаточно того функциона

Comment: Это был ужасный опыт :)

Answer (score 2):

Метод `Main()` является статическим. А поля `xlsAppWorkbook` и `xlsAppWorkbook` -- нет. Из статического метода нельзя обращаться к нестатическим членам. Объявите поля `static`:

```
private static Excel.Workbooks xlsAppWorkbooks;
private static Excel.Workbook xlsAppWorkbook;
```

Ну и не забудьте их проинициализировать в функции, иначе следующей ошибкой будет `NullReferenceException`.